# Call to undefined function 'save'

Tags: c++, function, return, call

I have been working on an address book in C/C++. I am getting this error. As I am new in programming, I am failing to understand reason behind it...

> Call to undefined function 'save'.

Here is the code of save function:

```
int save(struct contact _new)
{
     char dir[100]="c:\\programming\\address_book";
      get_dir(dir,_new.mobile_no,1);
      fstream file(dir,ios::noreplace|ios::out|ios::binary);
        if(!file)
        {
          file.close();
          return 0;
          }
          else
              {
            file.write((char*)&_new,sizeof(_new));
            file.close();
                sleep(2);
            struct _index in;
            strcpy(in.r,_new.mobile_no);
            ofstream index("c:\\programming\\address_book\\index.dat",ios::app|ios::out|ios::binary);
                index.write((char*)&in,sizeof(in));
            index.close();
         return 1;
        }
}
```

Here I am calling it:

```
if(save(_new))
    cout<<"\n\n\tContact saved successfully.";
  else
    cout<<"\n\n\tContact saving error.";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [call to undefined function in function main()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461465/call-to-undefined-function-in-function-main)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly common for learners of C\C++. You need to either put the save function before the main method or have a function prototype at the top of your file.

```
#include <stdio>
#include <otherHeaderFiles>

int save(struct contact _new)
{
     ......
}

int main() {
    if(save(_new))
        cout<<"\n\n\tContact saved successfully.";
      else
        cout<<"\n\n\tContact saving error.";
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio>
#include <otherHeaderFiles>

int save(struct contact _new);

int main() {
    if(save(_new))
        cout<<"\n\n\tContact saved successfully.";
      else
        cout<<"\n\n\tContact saving error.";
}

int save(struct contact _new)
{
 ......
}
```